# UML model transformation

Tags: model, uml, transformation, activity-diagram

I'm writing my bachelor thesis at the moment. Simply put, I have to do a model transformation where UML activity diagrams are the target model. The source model is a very uncommon diagram type but it's similar to activity diagrams (there is no English translation, that's why I didn't mention its name).

Right now, I'm not sure how to handle the actual transformation. I'd probably look at the meta models and then write some rules for the transformation. But how would I write a generator that does the transformation automatically? Are there any tools that are usually used for this?

Edit: More information:

So basically the source model is a model that presents a workflow using printed cards. There are different card types (like tasks, events, ...) that get arranged as necessary. My idea was to create a XML structure that describes this model and then use the XML to transform it into an activity diagram. Not sure if this is the best way to go, though.

Greetings

Comment: It is difficult to answer because you say nothing about the "source model", is it handle by a tool and if yes which one ? Is it defined just through a file following a given paradigm ? something else ?

Comment: So basically the source model is a model that presents a workflow using printed cards. There are different card types (like tasks, events, ...) that get arranged as necessary.  My idea was to create a XML structure that describes this model and then use the XML to transform it into an activity diagram. Not sure if this is the best way to go, though.

Comment: Ok so the input model is given through a source file (XML or other). You say "UML activity diagrams are the target model", in fact the target model is first "Uml activity", then may be diagram(s) showing (part of) the activity. Do you want to handle the activity into a given modeler and be dedicated to it or be more general and produce for instance the XMI file corresponding to the activity model ? (sorry I forgot to ask for detail concerning the target previously)

Comment: I appreciate your input a lot, thank you! First of all: What is the difference between saying that the target model is the activity diagram and the target model is "UML activity"? Sorry if that's a stupid question. About your question: I haven't decided yet but I think a graphical representation would be the best as a result. However, I guess the XMI could be enough..

Comment: UML is implicit in my answer, I distinguish an "activity" and an "activity diagram", this is a very common error, people speak about diagrams like is they define (model) the elements but this is not the case, the diagrams are 'pictures' whose only show parts of the elements from the model. In your case you can 'only' produce the activity by itself without associated diagram(s), or produce the activity more diagram(s).

Comment: Got it, that makes sense! Thank you! Do you have any advice on how I could implement plan? Any tools I should use?

Answer (score 1):

If both metamodel have a EMF decription, you can use ATL (https://www.eclipse.org/atl/) for your transformation.